# How do I number sections by parts?

Tags: formatting, numbering, lyx

I guess the title says it all. I want my sections numbered according to the Part I am currently in. For example, if I am working in Part 3, then I want my section to be numbered by 'Section 3.1', 'Section 3.2', etc.

Right now the section numbers continue from the part before. So, in Part 3 the sections are numbered as 'Section 15', 'Section 16', ....

Thank you for your help.
I am using `article` as documentclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write in your preamble either:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin{section}{part}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
```

(By default, the `part`counter is written in Roman numerals).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

the usual method for numbering one level within another is

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
```